# Error MSB3174: Invalid value for 'AssemblyVersion' for auto-incrementing version using %2a

Tags: c#, powershell, azure-devops, msbuild

I have one .csproj file. And as per the requirement. I have written PowerShell script to auto increment the Application Version.
I have used reference from the following link and used some of it's logic and integrate it with my PowerShell script.
https://github.com/deadlydog/Set-ProjectFilesClickOnceVersion

When I test PowerShell script, it shows that it will change the revision number to "%2a" which is used for auto increment operation. And creates new element in .csproj file named as "ApplicationRevision" which stores the actual revision number of version.
For Example, If Application version is `1.0.0.0` after increment, the application version looks like `1.0.0.%2a`. And Application revision element value is `1`.

After that, I have integrate this PowerShell script with Azure pipeline. But while running pipeline I got error that, "**Error MSB3174: Invalid value for 'AssemblyVersion'**". I checked Assembly version and manually update it. But still got the same error after manually incrementing the assembly version.

- Is there any way to resolve this issue?
- Am I getting this error because of using "**%2a**"

Comment: I think you can create an issue in the solution project: https://github.com/deadlydog/Set-ProjectFilesClickOnceVersion/issues

Comment: Have you tried using a literal `*` instead of what looks like the "url escaped" `%2a` value of it?